# How to add two or nth different list items with order into a new list?

Tags: javascript

The problem is how can I add `two` or `n` different list items into the order?
Then add them into a new list?

Anyone know is there a faster way to achieve this?

Thanks.

```
let resultList = [];

const list = [
  {
    "item": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "item": "ddd"
  },
];

const list2 = [
  {
    "item": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "item": "ccc"
  }
];

const list3 = [
  {
    "item": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "item": "yyy"
  }
];
```

```
// expected
resultList = [
  {
    "item": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "item": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "item": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "item": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "item": "ccc"
  },
  {
    "item": "yyy"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [can support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) new JavaScript features such as [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), you can map each object in `list` to an array containing the current object along with it's associated object from `list2` like so:

```js
const list = [{ "item": "aaa" }, { "item": "ddd" }]; 
const list2 = [ { "item": "bbb" }, { "item": "ccc" } ];

const res = list.flatMap((o, i) => [o, list2[i]]);
console.log(res);
```

This can be generalized for multiple lists:

```js
const list = [{ "item": "aaa" }, { "item": "ddd" }]; 
const list2 = [ { "item": "bbb" }, { "item": "ccc" } ];
const list3 = [ { "item": "xxx" }, { "item": "yyy" } ];
const arr = [list, list2, list3];

const res = arr[0].flatMap((_, i) => arr.map(a => a[i]));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: how about if I have n list want to combine? like more than two data list

Comment: @DonaldWu you can create an array of additional lists and then `.map()` each into an existing array which you can `.flatMap`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over first array and take the respective index value from other array as well and then push

```js
const list = [{"item": "aaa"},{"item": "ddd"}];
const list2 = [{"item": "bbb"},{"item": "ccc"}];

let final = list.reduce((op, inp, index) => {
  op.push(inp, list2[index])
  return op
}, [])

console.log(final)
```

---

What if i have n list, you can create an array of n-1 list list ( except the first array ). loop over the first array and get to push value from each list loop over remaining and get value at particular index.

```js
const list = [{"item": "aaa"},{"item": "ddd"}];
const list2 = [{"item": "bbb"},{"item": "ccc"}];
const list3 = [{"item": "eee"},{"item": "fff"}];
const list4 = [{"item": "ggg"},{"item": "hhh"}];

const remaining = [list2,list3,list4]

let final = list.reduce((op, inp, index) => {
  op.push(inp, ...remaining.map(v=> v[index]))
  return op
}, [])

console.log(final)
```

Comment: @DonaldWu Ahh sorry misinterpreted, now fixed see the updated answer

Comment: how about if I have `n` list want to combine? like more than two data list

Comment: @DonaldWu you can create an array of n-1 list and while pushing loop over them to get related index

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [
    {
      "item": "aaa"
    },
    {
      "item": "ddd"
    },
];

const list2 = [
  {
    "item": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "item": "ccc"
  }
];
var children = list.concat(list2); 
children=children.sort(function(a, b) {
  var x = a.item.toLowerCase();
  var y = b.item.toLowerCase();
  return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
})
console.log(children);
```